# Rails routing bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I feel a little sheepish for asking, but i am having trouble getting a simple rails route to properly work.

Really all I created was a simple view page, but i am having trouble routing to that view page.  (It has been quite a while sine i've done something like this)

My controller just has

```
def bio
end
```

my routes file is

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
  get '/bio' => 'home#bio'
end
```

And my view is here:

```
.col-sm-2.text-center
  =link_to bio_path
  %h3 bio
```

With what I have right now, the view that I am trying to route towards `=link_to bio_path` is linking straight to my home page instead.  Could anybody take a quick look at this for me?

I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change what you have to:

```
get '/bio', to: 'home#bio', as: 'whatever_bio'
```

Now you can say:

```
link_to "my link!", whatever_bio_path
```

Also, type `rake routes` in your console to get a listing of all the routes in your application. You can sift through the routes to see where `bio_path` routes to, and if you can't figure it out then update your answer with the results of `rake routes`.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't including enough information in your question - can you include the error you are receiving? You should have a "home" controller which looks as such:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def bio
  end
end
```

In your routes you declare a route to the bio action in your home controller:

```
  get 'bio' => 'home#bio'
```

In your views, you should have a "home" folder with a view titled "bio". Then when you navigate to localhost:3000/bio you should see your bio.html.erb or .haml view.